# How to clear cache since my restapi client is returning old data?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Our team has been creating API tests with Specflow using RestSharp as the API client. The API I am testing simply creates an asset (that has a few properties) with a POST method and then I use a GET method to get the data for the new asset, so I can deserialize and verify a few properties to ensure that the new asset has been created.

For example, I pass the new asset with a name property where Name="Asset15" (where a new asset of ID=15 is created from the sequence) and then I get the info passing the ID=15 to verify that the new asset with Name="Asset15" exists. Everything seemed to be working until recently.

Without changing any code, the test now creates the new asset with Name="Asset20" with ID=20, for example, but the GET method seems to be returning the record of Name="Asset19" and ID=19 instead, causing my test to obviously fail even when I see manually that asset of Name="Asset20" and ID=20 had been created.

There seems to be some caching issue and I was wondering what would be a way to clear this cache.

I have seen an article somewhere where the person fixed this by merely restarting Visual Studio. I tried that only to get results 2 records behind instead.

This is how I setup my test:

```cs
_settings.BaseUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseUrl"].ToString());
_settings.RestClient.BaseUrl = _settings.BaseUrl;
```

Execute the POST method to create the asset:

```cs
_settings.PostRequest = new RestRequest("CreateAsset", Method.POST);
_settings.PostRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
_settings.PostRequest.AddJsonBody(testData);

_settings.PostResponse = _settings.RestClient.Execute(_settings.PostRequest);
```

Later I execute the GET method, deserialize, and validate that the information is correct:

```cs
_settings.GetRequest = new RestRequest("GetAsset?id=20", Method.GET);
_settings.GetResponse = _settings.RestClient.Execute(_settings.GetRequest);

var deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
var output = deserial.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_settings.GetResponse);
var result = output["Name"];

Assert.That(result.Equals(testData.Name), $"Error: ...");
```

The test was passing and now it seems to be 1 or 2 records behind. Can someone help and let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the rest API owned by you? You need to see in the API code why it is returning incorrect data.

Comment: It is actually owned by my development team. They did not change the code either but I will check again. Since there were no changes I thought it had to do with caching. But I will check. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, the problem was with the API that has been changed and not the test code. Oops. Always assuming I am the problem. :-) So this can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was with the API and not the test code. This can be closed since it is a non-issue.